# LINQ Union different types - dynamically casting to an interface?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, union

I have 10 tables which are presenting to LINQ as different types, but share exactly the same properties. When I try to run a union on them, the compiler tells me that:

```
"Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LINQPad.User.TelJun2011>'"
```

The code looks like this

```
var jul = (from n in TelJul2011s select n);

var jun = (from p in TelJun2011s select p);

jun.Union(jul).Dump();
```

I've done my research and understand that unions cannot be performed across different types, I also understand that unions can be performed on anonymous types if they share the same properties. This option will not work for me, as I need all the properties from all the tables and don't want to have to type out the same anonymous type 10 times - once for each variable. I want the compiler to infer that they are all the same type based on the fact that all properties are identical.

I've already tried casting to an IEnumberable, Iqueryable, Datatable etc. using both the AsQueryable() type functions, and the "as" keyword. None of that seems to do the trick for me.

I'm wondering if there is some way of doing this by casting dynamically to a parent type. I can't edit the initial declarations of the classes, so can't implement a common interface on them to cast to. But is there some way I can downcast the types into a common interface when they are used, without writing a conversion from each type to a parent interface?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: AFAIK you already the only options... and said that you can't use them... so basically with these contraints the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, that is it. The proper solution would be to have a specific non tablet type (not anonymous) and select into this one. Source reason obviously is broken database design.

Comment: Not broken database design. I'm evaluating the potential to use linq as an ad hoc analytics solution to query multiple sources. Union of diverse sources is a basic SQL functionality commonly used for analysis even if I agree that it would be poor practise in production or a real application.

Comment: If you're using EntityFramework, classes are created as `partial`, and then you can create another .cs file with the same partial, forcing the classes to implement a custom interface which would have the needed properties.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of the `Union` will be an `IEnumerable<Xxx>` but in this case you have to specify what `Xxx` is. If the types `TelJun2011` and `TelJul2011` are *not* structs (value-types), you can utilize the **covariance** of `IEnumerable<out T>` like this:

```
jun.Union<object>(jul)
```

This works because `TelJun2011` and `TelJul2011` are both `object`, and then by covariance `IEnumerable<TelJun2011>` and `IEnumerable<TelJul2011>` are both `IEnumerable<object>`.

Of course `object` does not possess all the properties common to `TelJun2011` and `TelJul2011`. It would be better if these two types had a more useful common base class or implemened a common interface, because then you could say e.g.:

```
jun.Union<ITelMonth>(jul)
```

where `ITelMonth` were some type containing the common properties you want.

Comment: This answer is amazing... I hadn't really read into covariance at all prior to reading this as I wasn't aware it was such a powerful new language feature. Thanks again for sharing your knowledge Jeppe!

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that C#'s static typesystem won't allow what you're trying to achieve. You will have to cast the objects to a base type before union-ing them. That means if both have just `System.Object` in common, you would have to cast it either to `object` or (for .net 4.0) to `dynamic`.

The latter will force a dynamic typechecking:

```
class A
{
    public int Integer { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public int Integer { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new[] { new A { Integer = 5 }, new A { Integer = 6 }, new A { Integer = 7 } };
        var b = new[] { new B { Integer = 1 }, new B { Integer = 2 }, new B { Integer = 3 } };

        var u = a.Cast<dynamic>().Union(b).ToArray();

        var i1 = u[0].Integer;
        var i2 = u[1].Integer;
        var i3 = u[2].Integer;
        var i4 = u[3].Integer;
        var i5 = u[4].Integer;
        var i6 = u[5].Integer;
    }
}
```

In my opinion this is not an ideal solution, but this might help you.

Comment: I don't think you need the `Cast` method. Shouldn't the covariance of `IEnumerable<out T>` allow you to just write: `var u = a.Union<dynamic>(b);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EntityFramework (or any other framework, I guess), the classes auto-generated are marked as `partial`, such as the following:

**/Project/Data/TelJun2011.cs**

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class TelJun2011
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**/Project/Data/TelJul2011.cs**

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class TelJul2011
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What `partial` means is that you can create another file for the same class. The generated classes don't implement an interface, but you can easily make then implement your custom interface like this:

**/Project/Data/ITelMonth.cs**

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    public interface ITelMonth
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**/Project/Data/Partial/TelJun2011.cs**

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    public partial class TelJun2011 : ITelMonth { }
}
```

**/Project/Data/Partial/TelJul2011.cs**

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    public partial class TelJul2011 : ITelMonth { }
}
```

And having correctly defined the interfaces, then we can simply do this:

```
var jul = (from n in TelJul2011s select (ITelMonth)n);

var jun = (from p in TelJun2011s select (ITelMonth)p);

var bimester = jun.Union(jul);
```

And you can even access the common properties like such:

```
foreach (var e in bimester)
{
    e.Id.Dump();
}
```