# Union Multiple Classes, Sort on Common Interface

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, interface, covariance

This question is chiefly about LINQ and possibly covariance.

Two of my Entities implement the **IDatedItem** interface. I'd like to union, then sort these, for enumerating as a single list. I must retain entity-specific properties at enumeration-time.

To clarify by example, one approach I tried was:

```
Context.Table1.Cast<IDatedItem>().
Union(Context.Table2.Cast<IDatedItem>()).
SortBy(i => i.Date).
ForEach(u => CustomRenderSelector(u, u is Table1));
```

In trying to do this various ways, I've run into various errors.

- LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
- Unable to process the type '.IDatedItem[]', no known mapping to the value layer
- Unable to create a constant value of type 'IDatedItem'. Only primitive types
- etc.

The bigger picture:

- The IDatedItem interface shown here is a simplification of the actual shared properties.
- In practice, the tables are filtered before the union.
- The entity-specific properties will be rendered, in order, in a web page.
- In a parallel feature, they will be serialized to a JSON result hierarchy.
- I'd like to be able to perform LINQ aggregate operations on the results as well.

Comment: Why not `class`? I think all the mappings are done automatically so we don't need to care about class or interface.

Comment: You mean class inheritance rather than interface, with for example a Table-Per-Type EF implementation? Well, generally speaking, this interface is really a poor primary representation of the entities. You might ask what problem this causes. The interface we are discussing is specific to one set of views in my application. Since a class in C# can have only one immediate base class, this means I couldn't solve such a problem for other views the same way.

Comment: You can only do this if you do `AsEnumerable` just before the cast. But then you can't `Union`, unless you project to the same class first,and the Sort is done client side. Between a rock and a hard place...

Comment: I'm cool with sorting at the client side. If I need to sort at the server, I have the skills to do this with a sproc, and then I would probably switch to a model-first. But for now I just want to get this app off the ground. But you say I have to project to the same class to union? That's a non-starter because I need the entity-specific properties. I just found this related article on union and covariance, trying to understand... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540846/linq-union-different-types-dynamically-casting-to-an-interface

Answer (score 1):

This requires more space than a comment offers. On the other hand, this is not really an answer, because there is no satisfying answer, really.

For a `Union` to succeed, both collections must have the same type (or have intrinsic conversions to common types, that's what covariance is about).

So a first go at getting a correct Union could be:

```
Context.Table1.Select(t1 => new {
                                    A = t1.PropA,
                                    B = t1.PropB,
                                    Date = t1.Date
                                })
.Union(
Context.Table1.Select(t2 => new {
                                    A = t2.PropC,
                                    B = t2.PropD,
                                    Date = t2.Date
                                }))
.OrderBy(x => x.Date)
.ToList();
```

which projects both tables to the same anonymous type. Unfortunately, because of the anonymous type, you can't do `.Cast<IDatedItem>()`.

Therefore, the only way to get a `List<IDatedItem>` is to define a type that implements `IDatedItem` and project both tables to that type:

```
Context.Table1.Select(t1 => new DateItem {
                                    A = t1.PropA,
                                    B = t1.PropB,
                                    Date = t1.Date
                                })
.Union(
Context.Table1.Select(t2 => new DateItem {
                                    A = t2.PropC,
                                    B = t2.PropD,
                                    Date = t2.Date
                                }))
.OrderBy(item => item.Date)
.AsEnumerable()
.Cast<IDatedItem>()
```

Which (I think) is quite elaborate. But as long as EF doesn't support casting to interfaces in linq queries it's the way to go.

By the way, contrary to what I said in my comment, the sorting will be done in SQL. And you can use subsequent aggregate functions on the result.

Comment: Gert, thanks for the information. I've given it +1. I think I may be able to accomplish the letter of my question; I mentioned I'm OK with doing much of this client-side. Reason is, by requiring access to dissimilar properties through the union, either SQL would have to return empty columns for these (as per a Table-Per-Hierarchy EF class implementation), or SQL would have to return some hierarchical format such as XML, which of course EF doesn't parse. That makes it really fuzzy what the *optimal* way to do this is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code. My solution was to ensure all data was local, to keep LINQ-to-EF from trying to do all manner of things it knows it can't that were causing many unclear errors. Then a simple type declaration on the generic Union can take hold.

That means that, aside from the annoyances of LINQ-to-EF, the main issue here is really a duplicate of [LINQ Union different types - dynamically casting to an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540846/linq-union-different-types-dynamically-casting-to-an-interface) .

```
public virtual ActionResult Index() {
    return View(StatusBoard().OrderBy(s => s.Status));
}

private IEnumerable<DefensiveSituationBoardMember> StatusBoard() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime historicalCutoff = now.AddDays(-1);
    IEnumerable<Member> activeMembers = Context.Members.Where(n => !n.Disabled).ToList();

    // IncomingAttack and Reinforcements both implement IDefensiveActivity
    IEnumerable<IncomingAttack> harm = Context.IncomingAttacks.Where(n => n.IsOngoingThreat || n.ArrivalOn > historicalCutoff).ToList();
    IEnumerable<Reinforcements> help = Context.Reinforcements.Where(n => !n.Returned.HasValue || n.Returned > historicalCutoff).ToList();

    // Here's the relevant fix
    IEnumerable<IDefensiveActivity> visibleActivity = help.Union<IDefensiveActivity>(harm);

    return from member in activeMembers
        join harmEntry in harm on member equals harmEntry.DestinationMember into harmGroup
        join activityEntry in visibleActivity on member equals activityEntry.DestinationMember into activityGroup
        select new DefensiveSituationBoardMember {
            Member = member,
            Posture = harmGroup.Max(i => (DefensivePostures?)i.Posture),
            Activity = activityGroup.OrderBy(a => a.ArrivalOn)
        };

}
```